# compute mean of unique combinations in groupby pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have he following pandas dataframe:

```
data = DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'], 'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'], 'C' :[2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1]})
```

that looks like:

```
     A      B  C
0  foo    one  2
1  bar    one  1
2  foo    two  2
3  bar  three  1
4  foo    two  2
5  bar    two  1
6  foo    one  2
7  foo  three  1
```

What I need is to compute the mean of *each unique combination* of A and B. i.e.:

```
  A     B C
foo   one 2
foo   two 2
foo three 1

mean = 1.66666667
```

and having as output the 'means' computed per value of `A` i.e.:

```
foo 1.666667
bar 1
```

I tried with :

```
data.groupby(['A'], sort=False, as_index=False).mean()
```

but it returns me:

```
foo 1.8
bar 1
```

Is there a way to compute the `mean of only unique combinations`? How ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially the same as @S_A's answer, but a bit more concise.

You can calculate the means across A *and* B with:

```
In [41]: df.groupby(['A', 'B']).mean()
Out[41]: 
           C
A   B       
bar one    1
    three  1
    two    1
foo one    2
    three  1
    two    2
```

And then calculate the mean of these over `A` with:

```
In [42]: df.groupby(['A', 'B']).mean().groupby(level='A').mean()
Out[42]: 
            C
A            
bar  1.000000
foo  1.666667
```

Comment: @S_A Yes, I agree. Your answer is just as worthy of an upvote as mine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Here is a solution which you want. Firstly you make group corresponding column for making unique combination `A and B column`. Later from making group, you count `mean()` corresponding A column.

You can do this like:

```
from pandas import *
data = DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'], 'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'], 'C' :[2.0,1,2,1,2,1,2,1]})
data = data.groupby(['A','B'], sort=False, as_index=False).mean()
print data.groupby('A', sort=False, as_index=False).mean()
```

Output:

```
     A         C
0  foo  1.666667
1  bar  1.000000
```

When you `data.groupby(['A'], sort=False, as_index=False).mean()` do, it's mean you count `group_by` all value of `C column` according to `A Column`. That's why it return

```
foo 1.8 (9/8) 
bar 1.0 (3/3)
```

I think you should find your answer :) :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
test = data

test = test.drop_duplicates()
test = test.groupby(['A']).mean()
```

Output:

```
            C
  A            
bar  1.000000
foo  1.666667
```

Comment: Careful! I think the `drop_duplicates` option only works here because you *happen* to only have identical values for e.g. `('foo', 1)`. If you had a third `('foo', 1)` value, this would mess up the first average!

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.sql().aggregate("a,avg(c::int) c","a,b").aggregate("a a,avg(c)::decimal(30,8) c","a")


┌─────────┬───────────────┐
│    a    │       c       │
│ varchar │ decimal(30,8) │
├─────────┼───────────────┤
│ foo     │    1.66666667 │
│ bar     │    1.00000000 │
└─────────┴───────────────┘
```